# had to keep caps lock on for alerting unicode character

Tags: javascript, unicode

Here i want to alert a bengali letter on pressing 'a' button.But for this i had to keep caps lock on.I never worked on unicode characters.Any particular reason for this situation?How i can solve this problem?

```
var letter={
   '65':2438
}
 document.body.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
                                  alert(String.fromCharCode(letter[e.keyCode]));
                                  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the difference between small 'a' and capital 'A', both of which have respective ASCII values 97 and 65.

For capital letter 'A' (ASCII value 65)

```
var letter={ '65':2438 } 
document.body.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){     
    alert(String.fromCharCode(letter[e.keyCode])); 
});
```

For small letter 'a' (ASCII value 97)

```
var letter={ '97':2438 } 
document.body.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){     
    alert(String.fromCharCode(letter[e.keyCode])); 
});
```

Comment: Happy to help you. May I know what project does your question come under?

Comment: i was thinking of creating an application which can help me to convert a meaningful bangla word written using english letters to a similar word but eng letters converted to bengali.I mean the letter in the picture has same outcome as "A".So to get that letter i have to type "A" .I haven't started it yet.Consider this as my first step :)